# Android edit text autcomplete Best implementation or method?

Tags: android, json, android-fragments, autocompletetextview

Iam currently developing an **android** **e commerce** application,were we have API to find/search products, but unfortunately the result are not correct/accurate.(Poor API).
So iam planning to download the entire list of products (Around 500-1000 products) as json file/format to device from server which consist of **product_id** and **product_name**  and use some android auto complete method to search that product from json file.And i will keep flag whether new products have updated in backend , if so the json file get replaced.

**Is this a good method? Am i on right track. if not can you suggest some other methods and the procedure for doing AUTO Complete and product search.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: so you want to implement "client side search" instead of "server side search"? why do you think it will be easier?

Comment: i thought it will increase the search performance, and in some of tutorial ive saw they are doing in from local variables.so i can you suggest a good method. Iam in a confusion.

Comment: the server has the data stored in some sql database, so it would be easier to implement search using some sql query rather than client side searching

Comment: and the client side would be as simple as [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19860624/2252830)